# How to coat a thin electrical wire with carbon?

Tags: resistance, wire, copper, conductivity

I am looking for glue that can be used under a bio-solution. The solution is a bacteria culture solution (LB, SB). I have a chamber filled with culture solution and I would like to extend an electrical wire through it. I would like to put glue around the electrical wire to make sure it does react with the solution (Copper wire).
(metal wires react with water "e.g. corrosion")

Obvious solution:

1- use gold wires (too EXPENSIVE)

My Idea:

1- Use a carbon spray to coat the wires. I will just spray the wires with carbon. Carbon won't react with the solution. Is this a good idea? Do you know of a better solution?

[image]

Comment: Platinum wire might do the trick and is not prohibitively expensive

Comment: What is the purpose of coating the wire in carbon? Is it for electrical insulation and to prevent reactivity? Or just to prevent reactivity and you actually want it to be conductive? If the former, can you just use wire with teflon insulation? If the latter, can you just use raw carbon fiber? Is that conductive enough for you?

Comment: what is in the culture solution? what is the ph of the solution?

Comment: Gold-plated wire is also reasonably cheap since it's used for hobby jewelry making.

Comment: In your question you say "to put glue around the electrical wire to make sure it does react with the solution". Did you actually mean to say - to make sure it does NOT react with the solution?

Comment: I think pure graphite fiber tows will work as wires. If you need more conductivity, just use more tows. I have tried adding graphite powder to epoxy. The resulting cured solid is not conductive. It may be possible to make it conductive if you use a very high concentration of graphite powder, but  in that case it will be difficult to mix in the epoxy.

Comment: https://www.aircraftspruce.com/catalog/cmpages/carbonYarn.php

Comment: Too lazy to investigate, but the vanes in a Crooke's Radiometer look to me like they're covered in a layer of soot. Under the right conditions, you might just be able to form it in-situ, in much the same way that carbon-black is made. (a flame whose combustion is rendered incomplete, by means of a cool surface which it impinges upon)
You may have seen some produced by an amateur: cigarette-lighter soot on the ceilings of (some) public toilets, for instance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_black

Comment: You can use carbon vacuum evaporation process if really need to cover something with pure carbon. It is not complicated if you have such setup. Acupuncture needles are not expensive and gold-plated. Thin gold wire is widely used for integrated circuits packaging. If you know someone involved in such process, they likely will share a piece of it with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An applied carbon coating (sprayed, painted, dipped, etc) is going to have some type of filler material as an adhesive. If the adhesive is conductive it may react (through electrolysis) with the test fluid. If the adhesive is non-conductive it may not allow for the best electrical contact with the underlying conductor or the test fluid.

Using a solid carbon electrode may be better solution but there are also some issues to be aware of. A fibrous or porous carbon material may absorb some of the test fluid, while this may give a better electrical contact the carbon electrode would likely need to be discarded after the test as it might not be capable of being cleaned. If the test assembly is a onetime use item then perhaps this is acceptable. On the other hand if the carbon material needs to last for a long period and be capable of being cleaned then you may want to consider a more solid form of carbon namely graphite. There are many vendors that sell high grade graphite rods for use as electrodes.

Back to a more noble solution: Gold or platinum wire can be made in ultra thin forms, which would make the cost per a small length more reasonable. Ultra thin wires would be quite fragile so an inert mounting frame of plastic, Teflon, etc may be needed. Using a gold or platinum electrode should allow for improved clean-ability of the assembly. If cost is still an overriding issue then perhaps gold plated wire or plated strips could be used. Even further, if the fluid is not very corrosive then perhaps using 18k or 20k gold material would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you want to maintain electrical contact between your electrical conductor and the bacteria culture solution you may want to consider getting some carbon coated strip that you fit across the inside bottom of the culture dish. The ends of the strip can stick up out of the dish where you can connect the wires outside of the culture.

One place you may want to look is [here](https://dragonplate.com/dragonplate-carbon-strip-rectangle-035-x-106-x-24?gclid=CjwKCAjwyryUBhBSEiwAGN5OCHHGKYS3TXkET8v47bRFeKJMhdbHivO0vd5f9IatL2vJlxzfi11xvhoCO3gQAvD_BwE). .